# Realtime Workflow in Dynamics 365 Not Triggering when Record is Deleted

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm creating a Realtime Workflow in Dynamics 365 that is set to trigger on both "Before Record Status Changes" as well as "Before Record Is Deleted". I can confirm that it is firing and working well for the Record Status Change case, but for some reason it's not firing when I delete the same record in question.

Would anyone have any ideas why this could be happening? I've even looked at the Process Session history and can see that only Record Status Change instances have fired. None of the Delete instances have a log entry.

I should also add that the workflow is extremely simple and doesn't do anything different for a delete vs a status change, so any record that works properly for the Status Change should have the same result for the Delete.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a platform bug, I'd try [a] creating a new workflow from scratch to see it's not that particular process which is somehow broken [b] check if making the workflow asynchronous makes it fire, then putting it back to realtime and see if anything changes [c] open a support ticket [sadly, dyn365 shows lots of issues lately]

Comment: It's starting to look like it's something platform specific. I created a brand new workflow that triggers only on the delete. The only thing that the workflow does is cancel the workflow with a message. It still didn't trigger. We only recently upgraded to Dyn365, so I'm thinking that there's something under the hood that didn't get configured properly.

Comment: Have you got the issue sorted at the end? Did you raise a case with Microsoft support?

Comment: it's been a long time, but I seem to recall I had to recreate the objects and things suddenly started to flow. Possibly something to do with the underlying guids not matching possibly??

Comment: You are on CRM Online? Is this a core or custom entity?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to missing some required security privileges for the user running the real-time workflow.  The privileges listed here are listed in the Microsoft CRM/Dynamics 365 documentation at [Required security privileges for real-time workflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/create-real-time-workflows#required-security-privileges)

> "A security privilege named Activate Real-time Processes
>   (prvActivateSynchronousWorkflow) is required to activate real-time
>   workflows so that they can be executed. The Execute Workflow Job
>   (prvWorkflowExecution) privilege is required to start the workflow.

Note that when opening a security role (Settings - Security - Security Roles, these privileges will be listed as "Activate Real-time processes" and "Execute Workflow job" when looking on the Customization tab of the security role. "

Comment: This seems unlikely to be the cause since the workflow fires correctly on SetState.

Comment: I'd agree with you in that case as it wouldn't fire at all if you didn't have this security privilege.

Answer (score -1):

You can check scope of workflow. There is no platform bug I just created a RealTime WF on account delete and status change and that to Before... it worked fine.

Does any of the step skiping some logic.
Try creating Expense on Delete, if record gets deleted Expense entry will be created -just an example what I tried.

Keep WF Log Retension checked in order to track errors.